# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' attribute error

Tags: django, python-3.x, tuples

```
 add_form = CarAddForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        add_form = CarAddForm(data=(request.POST, request.FILES) or None)
        if add_form.is_valid:
            prof = add_form.save(commit=False)
            prof.profile = request.user.profile
            prof.purchase_yr = str(request.POST.get('purc_date'))
            prof.save()
            print("abc")
            print(add_form)
            messages.success(request,'Details saved successfully',  extra_tags='alert')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            add_form = CarAddFormCar()
            messages.error(request,'Something went wrong!',  extra_tags='alert')
```

> prof = add_form.save(commit=False) is creating issues. 
>   **prof = add_form.save(commit=False) is creating issues. 
>   **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you instantiate a form with data. Just do:

```
add_form = CarAddForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Also note, `is_valid` is a method, you need to call it:

```
if add_form.is_valid():
```

And there's no point recreating the form as empty if it is invalid; the user will just see your vague "something went wrong" message but won't know *what* is wrong. Remove that `add_form = CarAddFormCar()` in the else block.